# How to access individual form objects from a modelformset_factory?

Tags: django

I've deployed a formset using modelformset_factory. However rather than saving the entire formset, I need to loop through the forms in the formset, perform some logic on them, and save each one individually. At the moment I'm having to use the ID from each form in the formset to get the object it represents. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
def accounts_import(request,pk):
    account = get_object_or_404(Account, pk=pk)

    # Create transactions queryset for use in formset
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(account=account.monzo_account, import_type=None).order_by('-id')


    FormSet = modelformset_factory(Transaction, form=TransactionsImportForm, extra=0)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = FormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():


            for form in formset:

                object = Transaction.objects.get(id=form.cleaned_data['id'])
                # Do some stuff on the object
                object.save()
```

Comment: You could circumvent this by implementing a custom form with a custom `save` method or even by overriding the model's `save` method. If you want to do validation before saving, you could implement custom `clean` methods in your save.

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like form.cleaned_data['id'] returns the object and not the ID, so I got what I wanted.